# how systemjs-angular-loader.js works with bundling with systemjs builder in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, bundle, systemjs

In angular recent [change log](https://angular.io/guide/change-log#all-mention-of-moduleid-removed-component-relative-paths-guide-deleted-2017-03-13), it seems they are recommending using systemjs-angular-loader.js plugin instead of moduleid. As they said in the change log;

> All mention of moduleId removed. "Component relative paths" guide
>   deleted (2017-03-13)
>
> We added a new SystemJS plugin (systemjs-angular-loader.js) to our
>   recommended SystemJS configuration. This plugin dynamically converts
>   "component-relative" paths in templateUrl and styleUrls to "absolute
>   paths" for you.
>
> We strongly encourage you to only write component-relative paths. That
>   is the only form of URL discussed in these docs. You no longer need to
>   write @Component({ moduleId: module.id }), nor should you.

Looking at the source code of [systemjs-angular-load.js](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/src/systemjs-angular-loader.js), it's calculating the templateUrl (or stypeUrls) based on the loading file, in the quickstart case, it's app.component.js. However, in case of the production, we usually bundle the app together. Therefore, the js files in runtime are no long the files we developed. Anyone has idea to config the loader in such case?

Comment: For the application I work on, I stuck with the module.id approach. It's a small inconvenience to have to add each time and you don't forget as there is an error as soon as you test the component.

Comment: Thinking about this a little bit more - In a production build if you are bundling using the systemjs builder either bundles or static or with rollup - module ids and the systemjs-angular-load.js file are not needed.

Comment: Steverob2k, thanks! But in my case, I'm putting individual modules to different bundles and letting systemjs to analyse the dependencies and load them. I believe that's the selling point of systemjs, but I'm confused by the systemjs-angular-load.

Comment: Maybe this helps - module.id is something generated by common js. It’s nothing to do with an angular module. So you can add your angular module and it’s dependencies etc to a bundle js file and use the system js config file to redirect retrieving files to the bundle js file. Once you have that setup the module.id part is redundant as it’s the config setup that finds the js to load. In dev mode which is the QuickStart setup it’s more convenient to not have the config file.

Comment: module.id may be working. However, they are deprecating it from docs. I have to admit angular is very poor on describing production deployment. Probably, they are going to webpack and putting less and less energy on systemjs.